# Where to download Git in your local Wordpress directory?

Tags: wordpress, git

Where would I download Git on my Local Wordpress Environment So then I can create a branch and use it as a type of test environment. and have access to the other themes?

Comment: Seems like you would benefit the most from reading a git tutorial: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to test plugins and themes, it's most likely that your working directory should be established in `/wp-content` - it contains both `/plugins` and `/themes`. You'll want to make sure you have a `.gitignore` file that only tracks what you're working on.

If you are looking to work on changes to core, your working directory will almost always be the top-most WordPress root. That way, you can track [WordPress/WordPress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I put my GitHub folder in my themes folder and then I could use the repos in my GitHub folder on my local host WordPress site

Comment: I can create a branch and I could even use the branch as a test environment on my local host Just make sure to create a branch like `git branch New-Branch` then I used the command `git checkout New-Branch` then I logged out then back in after that I opened the repository `atom .` and I started  making changes and it works great.

Comment: but you must go and download git online the link is [https://git-scm.com/downloads](https://git-scm.com/downloads)